# Trying to read events from event hub in azure databricks in python

Tags: python, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I am trying to read data from event hubs. I am sending twitter data as json through event hub sender.
When I am trying to read the data and append it in a list I am getting the following error.Where am I possibly wrong?
below code:

```
        for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
            print(tweet)
            sender.send(EventData(tweet))


try:
    receiver = client.add_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=5000, offset=OFFSET)
    client.run()
    start_time = time.time()
    for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=100):
        last_offset = event_data.offset
        last_sn = event_data.sequence_number
        messages.append(next(event_data.body))
        total += 1
```

I am getting the below error:

**TypeError: 'dict' object is not an iterator**

Comment: The error message has stated that: 'dict' object is not an iterator. You should take a look at in which line the error throws, and which variable is dict that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message: TypeError: 'dict' object is not an iterator.

It means that you use a "dict" type instead of iterator. You should check in your code which "dict" type cause this error. Then you can use `iter()` function to convert the dict to iterator.